# how keep the calendar in the current selection month in multidatespicker

Tags: jquery-multidatespicker

There is a problem (when used the approach "From input") in [multidatespickr](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/) that makes the calendar back to the current month when you select two dates in some other month.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/URcqn/177/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#from-input').multiDatesPicker();
});
```

[Official demo](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/#from--input-demo) with problem too.

I'm use MultiDatesPicker v1.6.3

Answer (score 1):

simply add:
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { inst.settings.defaultDate = dateText; }

```
        $(function() {
      $( ".datepicker").multiDatesPicker({
        minDate: 0, showButtonPanel: true, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true          
            , onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { inst.settings.defaultDate = dateText; }

      });
    });
```

I found it [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Jquery/Q_28371867.html)

Comment: hello can you provide it in fiddle if you are free ?

let say i make default date 02/11/2016, 02/12/2016, 02/13/2016 then users cann add up date but cannot unselect default date, thanks